# Как определить какой элемент view нажат

Tags: android, gridview

Как узнать, какой элемент view в gridview был нажать?
каждный view состоит из textview, imageview, textview.
setOnItemClickListener определяет елемент gridview как одно сплошное

Пример

gridview 
состоит из 5 элементов каждый из них состоит еще из 3 элементов и того 15 элементов мне нужно узнать который с 15 был нажат

типу массив [i][j] где i-елемент gridview, а j-елемент в самому елементи

{textview(title)(0,0)},{imageview(image)(0,1)},{textview(text)(0,2)},
{textview(title)(1,0)},{imageview(image)(1,1)},{textview(text)(1,2)},
{textview(title)(2,0)},{imageview(image)(2,1)},{textview(text)(2,2)},
{textview(title)(3,0)},{imageview(image)(3,1)},{textview(text)(3,2)},
{textview(title)(4,0)},{imageview(image)(4,1)},{textview(text)(4,2)}

как мне узнать какой с етих елементов был нажат ?

Comment: Проставьте им id и по ним определяйте. Или отдельный слушатель повесьте на каждую вьюху

Comment: я понимаю но слушатель воспринимает весь блок (view) как одно сплошное.

Comment: Значит вам нужен первый вариант - отдельные ID на каждую вьюху и в слушателе, получив ID узнавать какой это именно ID

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо, буду пытаться